# Images are not displayed in background selection

Tags: wallpaper

When I try to select a new desktop background, only a few images are displayed, but I can select also images which are not displayed. If I move the system settings window around, then sometimes some more pictures show up, but only randomly. How can I see all?

Trying to describe it further: Usually all available pictures are displayed in the background selection window. But at the moment only the first five images are displayed, the rest not. Nevertheless I can still select them.
If I move the system settings window around (with the mouse), sometimes other images show up, but randomly.
The background selection window (including missing pictures) is shown below:
[image]
Output from `dir /usr/share/backgrounds` is:

```
164.jpg           elementaryos-default         Paris\ la\ Tour\ Eiffel.jpg
168.jpg           elementaryos-default_bak     Ryan\ Schroeder.jpg
16.jpg            elementaryos-default.jpg     The\ Coast.jpg
173.jpg           Horseshoe\ Bend\ Sunset.jpg  Tunnel.jpg
2.jpg             Jonas\ Nilsson\ Lee.jpg      Urban\ Dream.jpg
94.jpg            Lake\ Tahoe\ Colors.jpg      Water\ Lily.jpg
black_flower.jpg  Leaves.jpg                   Wild\ Night.jpg
Blueprint.jpg     Living\ Stones.jpg
Droplet.jpg       Mr.\ Lee.jpg
```

Comment: tbh its unclear to me, can you please modify a little bit for better understanding :)

Comment: sorry, what is "background selection window"?

Comment: Please [edit] and add output of `dir /usr/share/backgrounds`

Comment: @Ravan: Added edit

Comment: Please run `sudo apt-get install --reinstall elementary-wallpapers` and let me know :)

Answer (score 1):

Open terminal and run the command:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall elementary-wallpapers
```

You can reinstall from software center.

If not working, update to *0.3.2* would solve the issue.

Comment: Did not change anything.